# Scraping the value of a "data" or custom parameter inside of an html element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a web scraper for a class project. I'm using Beautiful Soup.

I want to scrape the values for the:

```
data-bathroom-value
```

and

```
data-bedroom-value
```

parameters inside of the following element:

```
<td class="floorplan-bed-bath" data-bathroom-value="1" data-bedroom-value="0">Studio / 1 bath</td>
```

basically trying to get the values for number of bedrooms and number of bedrooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse your html, then get the [attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) of your tag.

**DEMO**

```
>>> html_doc = '<td class="floorplan-bed-bath" data-bathroom-value="1" data-b edroom-value="0">Studio / 1 bath</td>'
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
>>> attrs = soup.td.attrs
{u'data-bathroom-value': u'1', u'data-bedroom-value': u'0', u'class': [u'floorplan-bed-bath']}
>>> attrs.get('data-bedroom-value')
u'0'
```

Comment: thanks. This got me closer, but I still don't know how to isolate just the number '1'. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/path/to/page")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for td in soup.find_all("td"):
    if "data-bathroom-value" in td.attrs:
        print("Bathrooms: ", td["data-bathroom-value"])
    if "data-bathroom-value" in td.attrs:
        print("Bedrooms: ", td["data-bedroom-value"])
```